# Is it possible to capture audio and store it in array?

Tags: javascript, audio, fft

I want to capture sound from mic or other input device and to store that data in the array and after that analize it with FFT using javascript, searched tons of sites and topics, couldn't find anything useful

Comment: With pure JavaScript? No way. Perhaps some integration with a Flash makes it possible.

Comment: @Havenard that's what I'm trying to avoid, is there some other way to do that not using a java applet / Flash ?

Comment: take a look here. http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/ few browsers support audio(/video) capture. I don't know if you can manage the captured media with js, I don't think. Anyway the link I agave you is a good point to start investigate

Comment: It's draft etc. But i think you're looking for WebRTC http://www.webrtc.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can, the API also provides an FFT analyzer (but only for live audio streams). It's called [Web Audio API](http://www.w3.org/TR/webaudio/) and is currently a draft, but is well supported by WebKit (you'll need to use prefixes) and a little less by Gecko. Look also http://caniuse.com/#feat=audio-api.

To get microphone audio, you'll need to use the [`getUserMedia`](http://www.w3.org/TR/mediacapture-streams/#navigatorusermedia) method, defined in the [Media Capture and Streams](http://www.w3.org/TR/mediacapture-streams/) draft, once you get the `MediaStream` you can create a [`MediaStreamAudioSourceNode`](http://www.w3.org/TR/webaudio/#MediaStreamAudioSourceNode-section), and attach it to the other nodes. To record audio samples, I'd suggest to try `ScriptProcessorNode`, the other useful node is the Analyzer node.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/K5Z83/) is a little experiment I did some months ago, I tried it only on Chrome, but should work with any WebKit browser. It basically takes the microphone audio stream and passes it to an analyzer node, which performs every frame (screen frame) an FFT, which is draw on the canvas and use to determinate the note (you only have to set the threshold with a mouse click anywhere on the canvas). Then the guessed note is reproduced on an oscillator node.

Comment: wow... just wow... thank you very much, I'll accept this answer as soon as I test it, I think I'll do that by monday